# concatenate all the elements in a column for every unique values in the row

Tags: r, shell, unix

I want to concatenate all the fast1 and fast2 files for every unique values in Sam_1.

for eg `cat SRR3493476_1.fastq SRR3493477_1.fastq  SRR3493475_1.fastq  > L1-A_1.fastq`

`cat SRR3493476_2.fastq SRR3493477_2.fastq  SRR3493475_2.fastq  > L1-A_2.fastq`

```
 Run_s           Sam_1   fast1                   fast2
    SRR3493476      L1-A    SRR3493476_1.fastq      SRR3493476_2.fastq
    SRR3493477      L1-A    SRR3493477_1.fastq      SRR3493477_2.fastq
    SRR3493475      L1-A    SRR3493475_1.fastq      SRR3493475_2.fastq
    SRR3493483      L1-B    SRR3493483_1.fastq      SRR3493483_2.fastq
    SRR3493481      L1-B    SRR3493481_1.fastq      SRR3493481_2.fastq
    SRR3493482      L1-B    SRR3493482_1.fastq      SRR3493482_2.fastq
    SRR3493487      L1-C    SRR3493487_1.fastq      SRR3493487_2.fastq
    SRR3493484      L1-C    SRR3493484_1.fastq      SRR3493484_2.fastq
    SRR3493485      L1-C    SRR3493485_1.fastq      SRR3493485_2.fastq
    SRR3493486      L1-D    SRR3493486_1.fastq      SRR3493486_2.fastq
    SRR3493478      L1-D    SRR3493478_1.fastq      SRR3493478_2.fastq
    SRR3493479      L1-D    SRR3493479_1.fastq      SRR3493479_2.fastq
```

Comment: @Gregor I think you need `aggregate(cbind(fast1, fast2) ~ Sam_1, FUN = function(x) paste(x, collapse = " "), data = df)`, but this doesn't separate `fast1` and `fast2`

Comment: I think he wants to concatenate the actual FASTQ files.

Comment: @AkselA , you are correct

Comment: @AkselA Now I see what OP really meant. Deleting my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use `tapply` and `paste` to generate the commands:

```
r1 = with(dd, tapply(fast1, Sam_1, paste, collapse = " "))
for (i in seq_along(r1)) {
    r1[[i]] = sprintf("cat %s > %s.fastq", r1[[i]], names(r1)[i])
}
r1
#                                                                        L1-A 
# "cat SRR3493476_1.fastq SRR3493477_1.fastq SRR3493475_1.fastq > L1-A.fastq" 
#                                                                        L1-B 
# "cat SRR3493483_1.fastq SRR3493481_1.fastq SRR3493482_1.fastq > L1-B.fastq" 
#                                                                        L1-C 
# "cat SRR3493487_1.fastq SRR3493484_1.fastq SRR3493485_1.fastq > L1-C.fastq" 
#                                                                        L1-D 
# "cat SRR3493486_1.fastq SRR3493478_1.fastq SRR3493479_1.fastq > L1-D.fastq"
```

You can then use for loop with `system` to execute each command (`lapply(r1, system)`).

I'll leave doing the similar step with the `fast2` column, or turning the above into a nice function that does both of them, as an exercise for the reader.

---

Using this data:

```
dd = read.table(text = " Run_s           Sam_1   fast1                   fast2
    SRR3493476      L1-A    SRR3493476_1.fastq      SRR3493476_2.fastq
    SRR3493477      L1-A    SRR3493477_1.fastq      SRR3493477_2.fastq
    SRR3493475      L1-A    SRR3493475_1.fastq      SRR3493475_2.fastq
    SRR3493483      L1-B    SRR3493483_1.fastq      SRR3493483_2.fastq
    SRR3493481      L1-B    SRR3493481_1.fastq      SRR3493481_2.fastq
    SRR3493482      L1-B    SRR3493482_1.fastq      SRR3493482_2.fastq
    SRR3493487      L1-C    SRR3493487_1.fastq      SRR3493487_2.fastq
    SRR3493484      L1-C    SRR3493484_1.fastq      SRR3493484_2.fastq
    SRR3493485      L1-C    SRR3493485_1.fastq      SRR3493485_2.fastq
    SRR3493486      L1-D    SRR3493486_1.fastq      SRR3493486_2.fastq
    SRR3493478      L1-D    SRR3493478_1.fastq      SRR3493478_2.fastq
    SRR3493479      L1-D    SRR3493479_1.fastq      SRR3493479_2.fastq", header = T)
```

Comment: excellent... I edited the output name by                                                          r1 = with(df, tapply(fast1, Sam_1, paste, collapse = " "))


for (i in seq_along(r1)) {
    r1[[i]] = sprintf("cat %s > %s_1.fastq", r1[[i]], names(r1)[i])
}

lapply(r1, system)

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this with `dplyr` + `tidyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  gather(variable, value, fast1:fast2) %>%
  mutate(variable = sub("(fast)(\\d)", "\\2.\\1q", variable)) %>%
  unite(Sam_1, c("Sam_1", "variable"), sep = "_") %>%
  group_by(Sam_1) %>%
  summarize(value = paste(value, collapse = " ")) %>%
  with(paste("cat", value, ">", Sam_1)) %>%
  sapply(system)
```

**Commands:**

```
[1] "cat SRR3493476_1.fastq SRR3493477_1.fastq SRR3493475_1.fastq > L1-A_1.fastq"
[2] "cat SRR3493476_2.fastq SRR3493477_2.fastq SRR3493475_2.fastq > L1-A_2.fastq"
[3] "cat SRR3493483_1.fastq SRR3493481_1.fastq SRR3493482_1.fastq > L1-B_1.fastq"
[4] "cat SRR3493483_2.fastq SRR3493481_2.fastq SRR3493482_2.fastq > L1-B_2.fastq"
[5] "cat SRR3493487_1.fastq SRR3493484_1.fastq SRR3493485_1.fastq > L1-C_1.fastq"
[6] "cat SRR3493487_2.fastq SRR3493484_2.fastq SRR3493485_2.fastq > L1-C_2.fastq"
[7] "cat SRR3493486_1.fastq SRR3493478_1.fastq SRR3493479_1.fastq > L1-D_1.fastq"
[8] "cat SRR3493486_2.fastq SRR3493478_2.fastq SRR3493479_2.fastq > L1-D_2.fastq"
```

**Data:**

```
df = read.table(text = " Run_s           Sam_1   fast1                   fast2
                SRR3493476      L1-A    SRR3493476_1.fastq      SRR3493476_2.fastq
                SRR3493477      L1-A    SRR3493477_1.fastq      SRR3493477_2.fastq
                SRR3493475      L1-A    SRR3493475_1.fastq      SRR3493475_2.fastq
                SRR3493483      L1-B    SRR3493483_1.fastq      SRR3493483_2.fastq
                SRR3493481      L1-B    SRR3493481_1.fastq      SRR3493481_2.fastq
                SRR3493482      L1-B    SRR3493482_1.fastq      SRR3493482_2.fastq
                SRR3493487      L1-C    SRR3493487_1.fastq      SRR3493487_2.fastq
                SRR3493484      L1-C    SRR3493484_1.fastq      SRR3493484_2.fastq
                SRR3493485      L1-C    SRR3493485_1.fastq      SRR3493485_2.fastq
                SRR3493486      L1-D    SRR3493486_1.fastq      SRR3493486_2.fastq
                SRR3493478      L1-D    SRR3493478_1.fastq      SRR3493478_2.fastq
                SRR3493479      L1-D    SRR3493479_1.fastq      SRR3493479_2.fastq", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it all in one like this

```
data <- read.table(text="Run_s           Sam_1   fast1                   fast2
    SRR3493476      L1-A    SRR3493476_1.fastq      SRR3493476_2.fastq
    SRR3493477      L1-A    SRR3493477_1.fastq      SRR3493477_2.fastq
    SRR3493475      L1-A    SRR3493475_1.fastq      SRR3493475_2.fastq
    SRR3493483      L1-B    SRR3493483_1.fastq      SRR3493483_2.fastq
    SRR3493481      L1-B    SRR3493481_1.fastq      SRR3493481_2.fastq
    SRR3493482      L1-B    SRR3493482_1.fastq      SRR3493482_2.fastq
    SRR3493487      L1-C    SRR3493487_1.fastq      SRR3493487_2.fastq
    SRR3493484      L1-C    SRR3493484_1.fastq      SRR3493484_2.fastq
    SRR3493485      L1-C    SRR3493485_1.fastq      SRR3493485_2.fastq
    SRR3493486      L1-D    SRR3493486_1.fastq      SRR3493486_2.fastq
    SRR3493478      L1-D    SRR3493478_1.fastq      SRR3493478_2.fastq
    SRR3493479      L1-D    SRR3493479_1.fastq      SRR3493479_2.fastq", 
    header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)


groups1 <- by(data$fast1, data$Sam_1, as.character)
groups2 <- by(data$fast2, data$Sam_1, as.character)

groups <- c(groups1, groups2)
fnames <- paste0(names(groups), "_", rep(1:2, each=length(unique(data$Sam_1))))
names(groups) <- fnames


for (i in 1:length(groups)) {
    file <- shQuote(paste0(fnames[i], ".fastq"))
    system(paste("cat", paste(groups[[i]], collapse=" "), ">", file))
}
```

The filenames will be `L1-A_1.fastq`, `L1-B_1.fastq` etc.